# Ruby script to read file line by line and do if statments with puts?

Tags: ruby, file, if-statement, line-by-line

I am trying to write a script that will fill out a mapping of equipment by using `if` statments on a text file.

Here is the code I have tried:

input.txt:

```
SWITCH
ROUTER
FIREWALL
ROUTER
ROUTER
FIREWALL
SWITCH
SWITCH
```

Ruby code:

```
IO.foreach("input.txt") do |type_equipment|
  if type_equipment = "SWITCH"
    puts "SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch"
  elsif type_equipment = "ROUTER"
    puts "ROUTER,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Router,Ethernet Router"
  elsif type_equipment = "FIREWALL"
    puts "FIREWALL,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Appliance,Firewall"
  end
end
```

The code runs but it is outputting this:

```
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
main.rb:6: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
main.rb:4: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
main.rb:2: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
```

I want it to evaluate each line in the file and if it matches an `if` statement, then output the associated `puts`.

I have also tied the `==` for the `if` statements but it only displays the result for the first line only with no warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Please indent your code properly
- As the error message suggests, you must use `==` instead of `=` for comparison (`=` is variable assignment)
- There is a newline at the end of `type_equipment` which you can remove with `String#chomp`
- Conditionals have the last expression as return value, so you can write a single `puts` in front of the `if` instead of repeating it inside the blocks
- I recommend using `case` instead of repetitive `if` statements

These suggestions would result in:

```
IO.foreach("input.txt") do |type_equipment|
  puts case type_equipment.chomp
    when "SWITCH"   then "SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch"
    when "ROUTER"   then "ROUTER,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Router,Ethernet Router"
    when "FIREWALL" then "FIREWALL,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Appliance,Firewall"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
main.rb:6: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
```

The answer is right in front of you.

When comparing two things you use `var1==var2`.

`var1=var2` is an assignment operator, it sets the value of `var1` equal to the value of `var2`, so your code should be:

```
IO.foreach("input.txt") do |type_equipment|
if type_equipment == "SWITCH"
  puts "SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch"
 elsif type_equipment == "ROUTER"
  puts "ROUTER,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Router,Ethernet Router"
 elsif type_equipment == "FIREWALL"
   puts "FIREWALL,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Appliance,Firewall"
  end
end
```

Comment: No this only outputs 1 result:
SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch

Comment: Im not sure, but I usually loop through a file in ruby like this:

http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/how-process-line-text-file-ruby

Comment: I think it doesn't work because there's a newline at the end of `type_equipment`.

Comment: you can do type_equipment.delete("\n")==var then

Comment: "I think it doesn't work because there's a newline at the end of type_equipment". `foreach` strips trailing new-lines when the record is read from a file.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I was thinking of the result after splitting a line, which normally won't return the line-end.

Comment: @theTinMan, I just deleted my comment. You might want to delete your last two, just to clean this up. I'll delete this comment later...

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to maintain your code when new equipment is added or existing equipment retired, consider using a hash:

```
hash = {"SWITCH" => "SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch",
        "ROUTER" => "ROUTER,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Router,Ethernet Router",
        "FIREWALL" => "FIREWALL,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Appliance,Firewall"}

equipment =
"SWITCH
ROUTER
FIREWALL
ROUTER
PINGER
ROUTER
FIREWALL
SWITCH
SWITCH"

equipment.each_line do |l|
  equip = l.strip
  puts hash[equip] if hash.key?(equip)
end
  # SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
  # ROUTER,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Router,Ethernet Router
  # ...
  # SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
```

or, if you prefer:

```
equipment.each_line do |l|
  equip = l.strip
  puts (hash.key?(equip) ? hash[equip] : "***What the heck is a '#{equip}'??")
end
  # SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
  # ...
  # ROUTER,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Router,Ethernet Router
  # ***What the heck is a 'PINGER'??
  # ROUTER,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Router,Ethernet Router
  # ...
  # SWITCH,BMC_COMPUTERSYSTEM,Network,Switch,Ethernet Switch
```

You could use `String#chomp` rather than `String#strip`, but I chose the latter because it removes any spaces fore and aft as well as the newline character. When reading from a file, you will want to use the enumerator [IO#foreach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-foreach).